I want count my order table each customers total order price using laravel
public function details_user($id){
    $user= order::find($id);
    $userid=$user->id;
    $data=order::where('seller_id','=',$userid)->get();

    $sub_admin= user ::where('price','$data')->count();


        return view('admin.try',compact('sub_admin'));

    }

I want to customers total order price and return it.

these models are strange

In your view, you can iterate over $userTotalOrderPrices to display each user's total order price. Also, $userCount will give you the count of users for whom you have calculated the total order prices.
here is code:
$user = User::find($id);

// Get the user's orders
$orders = Order::where('seller_id', $user->id)->get();

// Initialize an array to store user IDs and their total order prices
$userTotalOrderPrices = [];

// Loop through each order to calculate the total order price for each user
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $userId = $order->seller_id;
    $totalPrice = isset($userTotalOrderPrices[$userId]) ? $userTotalOrderPrices[$userId] : 0;
    $totalPrice += $order->price;
    $userTotalOrderPrices[$userId] = $totalPrice;
}

// Count the number of users and their total order prices
$userCount = count($userTotalOrderPrices);

return view('admin.try', compact('userTotalOrderPrices', 'userCount'));


if i add those code and show it in a blade file it show null....I just add those line in blade file to run.. {{json_encode($userTotalOrderPrices)}}

use only {{ $userTotalOrderPrices }}

Yes I solve this problem
